# Can VSCode initiate a 'git pull' every launch of a workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

[image: screen shot]My local git repositories always seem to get out of sync when using vscode as source controller.
Here is my problem, note it's probably intuitive or vscode's *un*intuitive source control interface. Note the 'git widget' shows nothing (if I'm in folder mode, say), but if I switch to source control I see that there's changes I need to pull down from the remote.

Is there any 'native' (meaning part of VSCode) way to automatically pull down changes when launching a workspace project? I feel a better solution would be to have vscode come up in the 'source control' screen when there are remote changes to pull down, or (better yet) just show the 'sync needed' as a changed icon for the source control.

I normally won't exit vscode without commiting and syncing the changes from local to remote, but if I fail/forget to do this, or if the change is done by another team member, or me on another machine, the initial 'git pull' will raise head/branch needs merging error, and prompt me to stash or rebase.

So I wouldn't think I could lose work if vscode automatically pulls changes, or tries to, from remote to local? I tried using a shell script with "git pull" in the tasks.json file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This question is likely just a grumble about the UI of visual-studio-code. As the pic above indicates, there is 1 item to be pulled from my remote, and a single click of the Sync button does that, but why is the "source control" icon appearing to have no tasks for me to do? Unintuitive, and a whole bunch of merge errors ahead unless I do that manual pull by clicking on the source control icon. Seems like there ought to be a little circle with a number, just like when there are uncommited or un-pushed changes??

Answer (score 0):

You can create vscode `task`. I've created this one to pull new updates whenever I open my project.
To create vscode task, you must create a `tasks.json` in `.vscode` directory.
Here is my tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "git pull",
            "command": "git pull; echo 'git pulled!'",
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information you can see vscode [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)